# Session Object Lost between pages with redirected domian on IE

Tags: asp.net, session, redirect

I have two domains. Something like:

```
1) www.mydomain.com
2) www.mydomain.virtual.com
```

Temporarly, i must redirect Domain 1 to Domain 2, so when someone use www.mydomain.com y redirected him to www.mydomain.virtual.com.

The problem I'm facing is that (only on internet Explorer) session object is now losted between my sub-pages inside my web. I créate a session on default.aspx, and when i redirect with response.Redirect to let's say main.aspx, the object has no value. Does anyone have any idea why? Thanks!

Comment: What version of IIS are you running? Are the 2 sites really just one site with different folders or are they different websites or virtual sites in IIS?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. is ISS 7 over Windows 2008 Server. The site is really only one (One folder) that i need to Access from both domains. Domain redirection is done with DynDNS account.

Comment: It is strange that it only occurs with IE as session issues should only occur at the server. Can you confirm this is definitely the case?

Comment: Yes I can confirme that. Also i can confirm that if i delete the redirection, and only stay with www.mydomian.com, the problem dissapear. It only happend when i redirect domain 1 into domain 2. Could be related to de dot in mydomain.virtual?

Comment: Its like my internal pages are not recognize by IE as part of the same domain, and the session is null on second page

Comment: Very strange, is there some reason you have setup the domains in this way. A virtual domain is usually www.domain.com/virtual although in this it is a different website so the session would be different ?

Comment: thanks @goku for your comment. Yes there is a reason. I need clients to connect to my site throght www.mydomain.com, but then i need to redirect them to www.mydomain.virtual.com (Host names are just examples). The reason for this is some blockings i'm suffering to my original host name, but i cannot change the URL from wich clients connect to my web server. This is just temporary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sessions are stored on the server, but the client needs to keep track of the sessionid. Usually a session cookie is used to store the sessionid.

What is causing this behaviour is that the sessionid cannot be resolved. Probably because the domain name is different and the browser interprets this as a third-party cookie, which can be (and probably is) blocked by the browser.

Since the sessionid cannot be resolved, all session info on the server is inaccessible. The link is broken.

Is it an option to copy the entire website to the temporary location and redirect all calls made to the original website to the equivalent page on the temporary location?

Otherwise you can solve your issue by using cookieless sessions:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.configuration.sessionstatesection.cookieless%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

For more information concerning cookies:

http://erik.io/blog/2014/03/04/definitive-guide-to-cookie-domains/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. And do you have any idea on why this only happends on IE and the website works fine on Chrome and Firefox?

Comment: That is why I added the second link. It mentions "Internet Explorer’s RFC-incompliant behaviour".