# Session null after redirect and return from another domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, webforms

We have a website *ASP.NET Web Forms* which uses another website (from another company, we have no control on it) service. in order to use their service we call their API and make HTML form (include returned value form the API) and post the form. something like this:

```
function foo(returnedValueFormApi) {
    var form = document.createElement('form');
    form.setAttribute('method', 'POST');
    form.setAttribute('action', 'http://that-company.com/...');
    form.setAttribute('target', '_self');
    var hiddenField = document.createElement('input');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('name', '...');
    hiddenField.setAttribute('value', returnedValueFormApi);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField);
    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
    document.body.removeChild(form);
}
```

Before call this method (in order to post the form), we create `Session`, e.g: `Session["Foo"]=10`.
After that user will be redirected to their website, do couple of things and then they send back the user to our website (and post some values, which is not related to the issue), inside `Page_Load` event of our callback page, we need to check the `Session` (*in our example, `Session["Foo"]`*). the issue is this session is `null`.

Highlights:

- This issue not related to expiration time, the user round tripe takes about 30 seconds.
- This issue not related to browser and specially `IE`
- If we change the `action` of `form` to point to one our website (even served from separate server), everything works. I mean we simulate the company inside one of our website to reproduce the issue, but we could not.
- This issue not related to `Response.Redirect`, which mentioned in some SO's answers.
- This Code worked for 5 Years! and just not work for 1 specified domain but others works!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Session Object Lost between pages with redirected domian on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041922/session-object-lost-between-pages-with-redirected-domian-on-ie)

Comment: No,This error occurred in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: The part of `lblSession.Text = Session["TestSession"].ToString();` is in your same solution? Is `example.com` part of another totally independent solution?

Comment: Yes, and about 'example.com' this site is not belong to us.