# ASP.NET MVC losing session unexpectedly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, session, 3d-secure

I have this really weird issues. My website is running fine for years using SQL Server Sessionstate. Just suddenly we have this problem. When I pay via hosted payment service, it require 3D Secure so the site redirect to 3D secure verification of the bank (at this point, session still correct as I have another tab open), but when complete and return back to our website, it generate a new session.

This is not because of session expiry, my session would stay for days if I don't go through the last step.
I put a log on Session_End in Global as well. But it not hit this event.
There is no session abandon in my whole project, so it might not be called somewhere.

Do you know what could be the cause for this please? I would be very grateful as I have been stuck for days.

Comment: this may help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041922/session-object-lost-between-pages-with-redirected-domian-on-ie

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/deepak.sharma00/using-cookie-less-session-in-Asp-Net/

Comment: Thanks, I will try cookieless setting see if any luck. It's weird though as my browser can still have cookie of the session id.

Comment: Unfortunately, this option won't work as it the return URL is fixed by payment gateway. So we can't get the session back when they return back to the site